# Query execute so slow when using NOT IN ( SELECT ... )

Tags: c#, mysql, subquery, query-performance

I have a mysql query which is workable but I found out that it is slow when I have added some conditions using NOT IN. Is here any suggestion that can replace the "NOT IN" by other words and still get the same result? Thank you for your help!

**My query:**

```
SELECT 
    CustomerId 
FROM 
    mktg_account ma  
    LEFT JOIN mktg_account_customer mac
        on mac.AccountId = ma.AccountId   
WHERE
    IsPurge = 1 
    AND mac.CustomerId NOT IN (SELECT mac.CustomerId 
                               FROM mktg_account ma  
                               LEFT JOIN mktg_account_customer mac
                                   ON mac.AccountId = ma.AccountId 
                               where IsPurge =0)  
    AND mac.CustomerId NOT IN (SELECT CustomerId 
                               FROM mktg_unit_booking 
                               WHERE DeadlineDate > Now()
                               AND IsDeleted <> 1 
                               AND IsApproved=1)  
    AND mac.CustomerId NOT IN (SELECT mr.CustomerId 
                               FROM mktg_reservation mr 
                               LEFT JOIN mktg_reservation_customer mrc 
                                   on mr.ReservationId = mrc.ReservationId 
                               WHERE IsDeleted <> 1 
                               AND IsApproved=1  
                               AND DeadlineDate > Now())  
    AND mac.CustomerId NOT IN (SELECT CustomerId 
                               FROM mktg_customer 
                               WHERE IsDeleted = 1 
                               OR IsApproved <> 1 )  
    AND IsDeleted <> 1 
    AND IsApproved = 1
GROUP BY 
    ma.TreeId, mac.CustomerId
```

**The related table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mktg_account (
  AccountId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  AccountNo varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  AccountStatus varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  TreeId int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  SalesDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PurchasePrice double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  SalesPersonId int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  FinancialTypeId int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  BillingCustomerId int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  EventId int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  CategoryId int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  RealEstateAgentId int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  BusinessSourceId int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  BusinessSourceOthers varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  SalesPromotionId int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  Remarks text,
  AgentName varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  AgentCompany varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  AgentContact varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  AgentRemarks text,
  CreatedDateTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  CreatedBy int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PurgedDateTime datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PurgedBy int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PurgedIP varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  IsDeleted tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  IsApproved tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  IsPurge tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (AccountId)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mktg_account_customer` (
  `AccountId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CustomerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsNominee` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `SortIdx` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`AccountId`,`CustomerId`),
  KEY `FK_mktg_agreement_customer_1` (`CustomerId`),
  KEY `AccountId` (`AccountId`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mktg_unit_booking` (
  `BookingId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UnitId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ProjectLevelId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ProductType` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SalesPersonId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReserveDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeadlineDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Remark` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedDateTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `CreatedBy` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CreatedIP` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `IsDeleted` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsApproved` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`BookingId`),
  KEY `UnitId` (`UnitId`),
  KEY `IsDeleted` (`IsDeleted`),
  KEY `IsApproved` (`IsApproved`),
  KEY `CustomerId` (`CustomerId`),
  KEY `DeadlineDate` (`DeadlineDate`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mktg_reservation` (
  `ReservationId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ProjectLevelId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SalesPersonId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ReserveDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `DeadlineDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `CustomerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Remark` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SolicitorId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedDateTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `CreatedBy` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CreatedIP` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `IsDeleted` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsApproved` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ReservationId`),
  KEY `CustomerId` (`CustomerId`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mktg_reservation_customer` (
  `ReservationCustomerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ReservationId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CustomerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsNominee` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ReservationCustomerId`),
  KEY `ReservationId` (`ReservationId`),
  KEY `CustomerId` (`CustomerId`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mktg_customer` (
  `CustomerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerCode` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CustomerSeriesNo` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CustomerFirstName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerSurname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChristianName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerName` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `BusinessSourceId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ContactMode` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MobilePhone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ICNo` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Salutation` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DateOfBirth` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gender` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Occupation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CorrespondenceTypeId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `FinanceSourceId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerGroupId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerCategoryId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MailingAddress` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `MailingPostCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MailingState` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MailingCountry` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReceiveMail` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedDateTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `CreatedBy` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CreatedIP` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `IsDeleted` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsApproved` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerId`)
)
```

**My EXPLAIN table:**
[image]

**UPDATED QUERY:**

```
SELECT CustomerId FROM mktg_account ma  
left join mktg_account_customer mac  on mac.AccountId = ma.AccountId   
where IsPurge =1 and not exists (SELECT mac.CustomerId FROM mktg_account ma  
left join mktg_account_customer mac  on mac.AccountId = ma.AccountId 
where IsPurge =0)  
and not exists (SELECT CustomerId FROM mktg_unit_booking where DeadlineDate > Now()  and IsDeleted <> 1 and IsApproved=1)  
and not exists (SELECT mr.CustomerId FROM mktg_reservation mr 
left join mktg_reservation_customer mrc on mr.ReservationId = mrc.ReservationId where IsDeleted <> 1 
and IsApproved=1  and DeadlineDate > Now())  
and not exists (SELECT CustomerId FROM mktg_customer where IsDeleted = 1 or IsApproved <> 1 )  
and IsDeleted <> 1 and IsApproved = 1
GROUP BY ma.TreeId ,mac.CustomerId
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps rethink your query a little. Seeing as you have AccountID as PRIMARY KEY on the mktg_account table there should be no duplicate accountids, making the initial sub query pointless:

```
SELECT CustomerId FROM mktg_account ma  
left join mktg_account_customer mac  on mac.AccountId = ma.AccountId   
where IsPurge =1
```

Is all you need to query.

This also seems to be pointless:

```
and mac.CustomerId not in (SELECT CustomerId FROM mktg_customer where IsDeleted = 1 or IsApproved <> 1 )
```

As your next line does the same Thing, albeit from another table.

Without seeing the data, i would try and replace the required Sub queries with joins

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to improve the query; I don't know which is better.  Both replace `x NOT IN ( SELECT ... )`

Plan A:

```
NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * ... )
```

Plan B:

```
LEFT JOIN ... WHERE .. IS NULL
```

On other topics...

- In `mktg_account_customer`, KEY `AccountId` (`AccountId`) is redundant and can be dropped.  Otherwise, the table is well designed (assuming `ENGINE=InnoDB`)
- Indexes on flags (eg, KEY `IsApproved` (`IsApproved`)) are rarely useful.  Composite indexes starting with a flag *may* be useful.
- It *may* be worth removing purged, deleted, unapproved, and beyond-deadline rows from the table.
- When `JOINing`, please use aliases.  Example:  It is not obvious which table this comes from `where IsPurge =0`.
- Don't say `LEFT` when `JOIN` works the same.  `LEFT` implies that the 'right' table may have a missing row that you want to have as `NULLs`.  I'm pretty sure the one with `where IsPurge =0` will act the same -- if the row is missing, `IsPurge` will be `NULL`, hence not `0`.

**Edit:**  Perhaps this is will do the `EXISTS` approach:

```
SELECT  CustomerId
    FROM  mktg_account ma
    left join  mktg_account_customer mac  ON mac.AccountId = ma.AccountId
    where  ma.IsPurge =1
      and  ma.IsDeleted <> 1
      and  ma.IsApproved = 1
      and  not exists 
        ( SELECT  *
            FROM       mktg_account ma2
            left join  mktg_account_customer mac2  ON mac2.AccountId = ma2.AccountId
            where  IsPurge =0
              AND  mac.CustomerId = mac2.CustomerId
        )
      and  not exists 
        ( SELECT  *
            FROM  mktg_unit_booking
            where  DeadlineDate > Now()
              and  IsDeleted <> 1
              and  IsApproved=1
              AND  CustomerId = mac.CustomerId
        )
      and  not exists 
        ( SELECT  *
            FROM       mktg_reservation mr
            left join  mktg_reservation_customer mrc
                   ON mr.ReservationId = mrc.ReservationId
            where  IsDeleted <> 1
              and  IsApproved=1
              and  DeadlineDate > Now()
              AND  mr.CustomerId= mac.CustomerId
        )
      and  not exists 
        ( SELECT  *
            FROM  mktg_customer
            where ( IsDeleted = 1  or  IsApproved <> 1 )
              AND  CustomerId = mac.CustomerId
        )
    GROUP BY  ma.TreeId, mac.CustomerId
```

Comment: I have tried to replace the NOT IN by NOT EXISTS but error thrown. It shows that (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS (SELECT mac.CustomerId FROM mktg_account ma  
left join mktg_account_cust' at line 3 )

Comment: Need some context...  It should look something like `AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ...)`

Comment: Hi. I have just updated my query in my question. Can you help me to see whether it is a correct way to use NOT EXISTS? Thank you!